# how to combine templates angularjs 1

Tags: angularjs, templates

I have (3) three template, first it's home and login, second it's admin, third user. the question is how to combine or link that three template. oh ya second and third template link by login in first template. I use angularjs version 1/first.
my img template :

[first, second and third template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieAeJ.jpg)

it's my app and controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  //home
  .when("/", { templateUrl: "partials/apotek_home.html", controller: "PageCtrl" })
  // Pages
  .when("/apotek_home", { templateUrl: "partials/apotek_home.html", controller: "PageCtrl" })
  .when("/apotek_login", { templateUrl: "partials/apotek_login.html", controller: "PageCtrl" });
}]);

app.controller('PageCtrl', function( /* $scope, $location, $http */ ) {
  console.log("Page Controller reporting for duty.");
  // Activates the Carousel
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000
  });

  $('.tooltip-social').tooltip({
    selector: "a[data-toggle=tooltip]"
  });
});
```

Comment: By "link" you mean `<a href="xx"></a>` this kind of link?

Comment: there's 3 template, 1(home & login), 2(admin), 3(user) after sukses login redirect to another view(user / admin) yes. my index : <div ng-include='"templates/header.html"'></div> <div ng-view></div> <div ng-include='"templates/footer.html"'></div>. the question is how i can display template(admin/user) when login success, it's from 1 index, it's my problem, i don't understand about it. i am looking example in any template but many of them only one template(display, view) not like mine. my 1 template, second & third is different, how to combine it, that's make me confusing. thanks.

Comment: you might want to consider using `ui-router` for multiple-view support on same route (called `state` in `ui-router`)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand your question. There's login page(view) and after a successful login, you have to redirect user to another view. No ? And in that view, when some other button or link clicked, you have to redirect to another view. So you can use following command to do that.

```
$location.path('/apotek_home');
```

After the login, if you want to go to the home page, you can use this.
Please take a look at this link : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Ask if there's anything you want to know.

Comment: there's 3 template, 1(home & login), 2(admin), 3(user) after sukses login redirect to another view(user / admin) yes. my index : <div ng-include='"templates/header.html"'></div> <div ng-view></div> <div ng-include='"templates/footer.html"'></div>. the question is how i can display template(admin/user) when login success, it's from 1 index, it's my problem, i don't understand about it. i am looking example in any template but many of them only one template(display, view) not like mine. my 1 template, second & third is different, how to combine it, that's make me confusing. 

thanks. help me